# Slow performance with simple 3d scene

Tags: godot

I am trying to create a tentacle in Godot. I tried making it in Blender and then putting bones in, but I couldn't get it to work, so I'm trying something simpler: I have 13 CSGMesh (Cylinder meshes) to represent tentacle segments, and each segment is parent to the rest of the tentacle.

```
tentacle
+-> segment1
    +-> segment2
        +-> segmen...
```

So what I'm trying to do is very simple, on every update, I modify the Z rotation of the segment back and forth. The effect does look like a tentacle waving, but I'm getting maybe 1-2 frames per second. There isn't anything else in the scene, so I feel like maybe I'm doing something incorrectly, although I can't tell what it is.

The thing I'm doing is very simple, but it's a lot of code, so the relevant bit is here:

```
public class tentacle4 : Spatial
{
    private class SegmentPosition
    {
        // ... I cut out the stuff in here for keeping track of position and rotation speed

        // the actual segment in the scene
        public Spatial Node { get; set; }

        public void RotateZ(float delta)
        { 
            // the bit that actually roates is:
            this.Node.Rotation = new Vector3(0, 0, proposed);
        }
    }

    // No meaningful difference here in performance between
    // this and _PhysicsProcess()
    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
       foreach (var segment in Segments)
       {
          segment.RotateZ(delta);
       }
    }

}
```

What could I be doing wrongly to make it perform so poorly? I assume I'm doing the rotation at the wrong time in the pipeline, although I can't tell when is correct. I'll mention that the preview in Godot proper runs just fine, and when running the project (in either GLES2 or GLES3) the computer isn't strained-- neither CPU (i7-8705) nor GPU (Vega GL) seem to care.

Comment: It looks like the way I'm doing it is incorrect. I switched to, instead of setting Rotation on every update, creating a Tween node and setting it to `InterpolateProperty()` on `rotation_degrees:z`, which is smoother-- but it still looks pretty choppy. I put a `GD.Print()` in every `_Process()`, which is saying that `delta`=0.016, so I guess I'm getting 60 fps? It feels more like 20ish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSG nodes aren't meant to be moved every frame, especially in deeply nested trees like this. CSG operations are expensive and they're performed on the CPU only. Only use boolean operations when you actually need them. When you don't need boolean operations, use MeshInstance instead.

Also, to deform a mesh, you can look into [writing a vertex shader](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/shaders/your_first_shader/your_first_3d_shader.html). Unlike CSG or scripting, shader code runs on the GPU, which is faster, especially with large amounts of instances.

Comment: That was it. Once I removed the CSG nodes and replaced them with Mesh Instances it started being smooth: https://github.com/f00f-nyc/Kraken